# In SQL, Is there any way to construct a variable that tracks historical data within multiple groups?

Tags: sql, variables, group-by, count, google-bigquery

I have inquiries about the "variable construction" in the SQL, more specifically Big Query in the GCP (Google Cloud Platform). I do not have a deep understanding of SQL, so I am having a hard time manipulating and constructing variables I intend to make. So, any comment would be very appreciated.

I’m thinking of constructing two variables, which seems quite tricky to me. I’d like to briefly introduce the structure of this dataset before I inquire about the way of constructing those variables. This dataset is the historical record of game matches played by around 25,000 users, totaling around 100 million matches. 10 players participate in a single match, and each player choose their own hero. Due to the technical issue, I can only manipulate and construct those two variables through Big Query in the GCP (Google Cloud Platform).

**Constructing “Favorite Hero” Variable**

First, I am planning to construct a “favorite hero” variable within match-user level. As shown in the tables below, the baseline variables are 1)match_id (that specifies each match) 2)user_id(that specifies each user) 3) day(that indicates the date of match played) 4)hero_type(that indicates which hero did each player(user) choose).
Let me make clear what I intend to construct. As shown below, the user “3258 (blue)” played four times within the observation period. So, for the fourth match of user 3258, his/her favorite hero_type is 36 because his/her cumulative favorite here_type is 36. Please note that the “cumulative” does not include the very that day. For example, the user “2067(red)” played three times: 20190208, 20190209, 20190212. Each time, the player chose heroes 81, 81, and 34, respectively. So, the “favorite_hero” for the third time is 81, not 34. Also, I’d like to set the number of favorite_hero is 2. 
The important thing to note is that there are consecutive but split tables as shown below. Although those tables are split, the timeline should not be discontinued but be linked to each other.

[image]

**Constructing “Familiarity” Variable**

I think the second variable I intend to make is quite trickier than the previous one. I am planning to construct a “met_before” variable that counts the total number of cases where each user met another player (s). For example, in the match_id 2, the user 3258(blue) and 2067(red) met each other previously at the match_id 1. So, each user has a value of 1 for the variable “met_before” So, the concept of “match_id” particularly becomes more important when making this variable than the previous one, because this variable is primarily made based on the match_id. Another example is, for the match_id 5, the user 3258(blue) has the value of 4 for the variable “met_before” because the player met with user 2386(green) for two times (match_id 1 and 3) and with user 2067(red) for the two times(match_id 1 and 2), respectively. 
Again, the important thing to note is that there are consecutive but split tables as shown below. Although those tables are split, the timeline should not be discontinued but be linked to each other.

[image]

Comment: hi dear friend, please add your query and tables sample code for give the best feedback

Comment: for best result provide "sample data" in a manner that we can use, images of data are useless from that perspective, please take a moment to read  `How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example` https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also don't make the question so long that we need to read a novel. Ask one question at a time, not several.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, it would be better if you could provide sample data.
Also, there are 2 separate problems in the question. It would be better to create 2 different threads for them.

I prepared sample data from your screenshots and the code you need.
So you can try the code and give feedback according to the output. So if there is anything wrong, we can iterate it.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION find_fav_hero(heroes ARRAY<INT64>) AS 
((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(hero as string) ORDER BY hero)
  FROM (
    SELECT *, max(cnt) over () as max_cnt
    FROM (
      SELECT hero, count(*) as cnt
      FROM UNNEST(heroes) as hero
      GROUP BY 1
    )
  )
  WHERE cnt = max_cnt
));

WITH 
rawdata as (
  SELECT 2386 AS user_id, 20190208 as day, 30 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 3268 AS user_id, 20190208 as day, 30 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2067 AS user_id, 20190208 as day, 81 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 3268 AS user_id, 20190209 as day, 36 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2067 AS user_id, 20190209 as day, 81 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2386 AS user_id, 20190210 as day, 3 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 3268 AS user_id, 20190210 as day, 36 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2386 AS user_id, 20190212 as day, 203 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 3268 AS user_id, 20190212 as day, 36 as hero_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2067 AS user_id, 20190212 as day, 34 as hero_type
)
SELECT *, 
  count(*) over (partition by user_id order by day) - 1 as met_before,
  find_fav_hero(array_agg(hero_type) over (partition by user_id order by day rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding )) as favourite_hero
from rawdata
order by day, user_id
```